# Write barrier when swapping array elements

Tags: ocaml

Consider the following code:

```ml
let swap_array_elements (arr:string array) (i:int) (j:int) =
  let v_i = arr.(i)
  and v_j = arr.(j) in
  arr.(i) <- v_j;
  arr.(j) <- v_i
```

In the AMD64 assembly code produced by `ocamlopt` the line below occurs twice in the main path:

```
call    caml_modify@PLT
```

Makes me wonder... why are there two write barriers  when the liveness of the array elements `v_i` and `v_j` remains the same?

(I'm under the simplistic impression that (non-float) arrays in OCaml are blocks of some immutable length which are traversed by the GC in the marking phase.)

Or: is there a special OCaml idiom that allows me to avoid above write barriers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are doing two separate `write`s, there are no way to avoid two write barrier as far as I know.

In particular, since the swap is not atomic, there is no guaranteed that the values written are still in the array at the time of of the `write`s.

There is moreover the issue that the write barrier also tracks pointers to the minor heap (aka the nursery heap) written inside the major heap, and the swap might spread those pointers.